# cannot push to a private remote branch (happens repeatedly)

Tags: git

I created some private remote branch and pushed to it already successfully.
Now I cannot anymore:

```
[user_name@ localMachine /directory]% git push
To git@remoteMachine:/remoteDir
 ! [rejected]        VFR_10_12_2018 -> VFR_10_12_2018 (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@remoteMachine:/remoteDir'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
[user_name@ localMachine /directory]%
```

I already did the following:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin VFR_10_12_2018
git pull --rebase
```

The last command reported uptodate.
I also temporary switched to the main branch and updated this one -- problem persists.

Note that I already know, that there is the -f option to force a push. But this ought not to be necessary, as no accident happened and nobody else is writing into this branch. And this is happening all the time.

Comment: Use a GUI Git client to see how the branches diverged.

Comment: did you amend a commit or rebase? If so, you gotta use the -f flag anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have anything to commit,

Just pull the latest changes from the remote to local as,

```
git pull origin VFR_10_12_2018
```

or if you have any changes in the local,

just stash those changes and pull from the remote to local and unstash it,

```
git stash
git pull origin VFR_10_12_2018
git stash apply
```

after that just add to remote and commit.